# why is output 2 3 0?

Tags: c, output

I'm solving some exam questions, and I came across this one and I just don't get it.

```
   int main()
    {
       int a[3+2] = {1, 2, 3}, i;
       for(i = 0; a[i++]++;)
          printf("%d", a[i]);
    return 0;
    }
```

Why is output of this code 2 3 0? I tried few ways of thinking but cant undertsand it.

Comment: This is badly-written code.  It's fine to ask how it works, just make sure you never write code like this.  One of the responsibilities of a programmer is to not write code that is unnecessarily clever or likely to be confusing to the next programmer reading it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first iteration, `a[i++]++` will do two things:

1. Return value of `i` and increment it (first `++`), thus leaving us with `a[0]` (`i` initialised as 0) as of now,
2. Now coming to the `a[0]`, it's post-incremented again (second `++`), so this finally returns `a[0]` and then increments it.

So for the first iteration, the value returned in `for`'s condition is `a[0]` which is 1, thus the loop will proceed to its body.

Coming to the body of our for loop, we now have two changes from the above statement, `i` and `a[i]` both incremented, so we have `i = 1` and `a[0] = 2` (`a[0]` was incremented by 1, remember the outer `++`).

Continuing in the same fashion, we will move on to `i = 2, a[1] = 3` (`a[1]` was 2 but post-incremented, so became 3).

After this, again coming back to the loop's conditional, we have `i` (=2) and `a[i]` (=3) both post-incremented again, so the value returned will be `a[i]` that is `a[2]` (since `i` is 2 as of now, now it is incremented after being returned), so `i` would be 3 in the next statement inside for loop's body, which would make the array element as `a[3]` that is 0 (that's why you get `0` in the last iteration).

Since `i = 3` and from the array declaration, we have the default value of `a[3]` as 0, it gives `i = 3`, `a[i] = a[3] = 0` in the next iteration.

Again coming back to the loop conditional, it will return `a[i]` which at this point is `a[3]` that is 0, thus failing the condition and hence halting the loop. Hence, you don't print anything afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

```
  int a[3+2] = {1, 2, 3}, i;
  for(i = 0; a[i++]++;)
      printf("%d", a[i]);
```

is equivalent of making it more simple to read

```
  int a[3+2] = {1, 2, 3, 0, 0}, i;
  for(i = 0; a[i];) {
      a[i] += 1;
      i += 1;
      printf("%d", a[i]);
  }
  a[i] += 1;
```

all the `++` are postr incr, so the values are used *before* the incr in the test of the for

note the result is undefined in case of pre incr (`++a[++i]`) because the order of the two incr is unspecified

Comment: Using ++ in this code is perfectly fine, so long as you don't combine them in the way that the OP does.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am not sure to understand you, do you say the behavior is undefined because the order of the two ++ is undefined ? for me no because there are **post** incr rather than **pre** incr => their order is not relevant

Comment: I mean, you could just as well have written `a[i] = a[i] + 1`.  `a[i]++` is perfectly acceptable and understandable to everyone.

Comment: This is not the same, in the OP code the array will have (23410) and with yours 23400

Comment: @dreamcrash: All the more reason not to write code like this in the first place.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, I agree I never understood the point of writing like that

Comment: @dreamcrash you are right, I was focus on the print and forgot to put the incr after the loop, thank you, corrected

Answer (score 1):

It happens so, because in *for* you have a[i++]. When *i = 3* the count in array is 4 and you receive the default value of *int*, which is 0, your array being [1, 2, 3, 0, 0]. Sorry for my English if is bad.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
int a[3+2] = {1, 2, 3}
```

is the same as

```
int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 0, 0}
```

Your loop:

```
for(i = 0; a[i++]++;)
```

stops printing as soon as a[i] == 0, in your case on the 4th position. Your loop is equivalent to

```
 int a[3+2] = {1, 2, 3, 0, 0}, i;
 for(i = 0; a[i] != 0;)
 {  
    a[i]++;
    i++;
    printf("%d", a[i]); 
 }
 a[i]++;
 i++;
```